# Text search order by proximity using MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, geolocation, full-text-search

Is there some way to do a text search in MongoDB and order the results by proximity given a location? I'm prototyping a purchase-sale app and I need that the user can have all the results that match his text query and in turn near where there is located.

Answer (score 0):

If you have latitude and longitude in your data, seems like it would be something like:

```
db.collection.find({ $and: [
  { lat: { $gt: value1, $lt: value2 } }, 
  { lon: { $gt: value1, $lt: value2 } },
  { name: 'some search string' }
] });
```

Comment: You aren't using a text index that is mandatory for a text query and also    geospatial information can't be treat as simple numbers using $gt or similars. That's a very bad idea to achieve what I actually need to solve.